# Android recyclerview: how do I fix passing data to a new activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer in my adapter file.  For each RecyclerView item, I pass a time difference in milliseconds between two dates as "diff" with a bundle to the MainActivity.  I get the bundle and then pass "diff" in an intent to the Details Activity.  When I setText to a TextView in Details Activity, I get zeroes.  What am I missing here?

```
Adapter
...
final long countDownInterval = 250;
itemHolder.timer = new CountDownTimer(diff, countDownInterval) {
    public void onTick(long diff) {
        ... 
        bundle.putLong("spantimeinhours",diff);
    }

    public void onFinish() {                    
    }
}.start();
passDataFromAdapter(bundle);

Main Activity
...
public void passDataFromAdapter(Bundle bundle) {        
    joe = bundle.getLong("spantimeinhours");
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, final View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Details.class);        
    intent.putExtra("adapterSpanTimeInHours",joe);        /
    startActivity(intent);
}  

Details Activity
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    joe = intent.getLongExtra("adapterSpanTimeInHours",0);

    weeks = joe / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    days = joe  / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) % 7;
    hours = joe / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
    timeinweeks = String.format(Locale.US, "%2dW %2dD %2dh", weeks, days, hours);

    cb11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cb11);
    cb11.setText(timeinweeks);
}
```

Comment: check the value of 'joe' in onitemclick, is it 0 or it has the value you requied

Comment: Ah Ok.  What is best way to test the value?

Comment: put the log in onitemclick and in passDataFromAdapter, to see is the value get changed

Comment: I used Log.d in onItemClick and it shows a value of 0.  So it is not getting the time difference correctly from the adapter, correct?

Comment: from Log.d in passDataFromAdapter() in the MainActivity the value is zero.  So is there something wrong with "joe = bundle.getLong("spantimeinhhours");"?

Comment: I guess the logic you are using is somewhere wrong..  the bundle inside the onTick is not same as of the bundle `passDataFromAdapter(bundle);`. perhaps you can use callback mechanism.. whenever onTick get called, you can send callback from ontick to Mainactivity and use the updated value in onitemclick

Answer (score 0):

I see you put long to Bundle `joe = bundle.getLong("spantimeinhours");` But you parse data from Intent `joe = intent.getLongExtra("adapterSpanTimeInHours",0);`
You can review.

Answer (score 0):

Mainactivity..

```
public interface valueUpdater(){
     void onvalueUpdate(int updatedValue)
}

long diff;

 Adapter abc = new Adapter(your date .. new valueUpdaer(){

  void onvalueUpdate(int updatedValue){
      diff = updatedValue; // get the updated value all the time
  }
});

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, final View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Details.class);        
    intent.putExtra("adapterSpanTimeInHours",diff );        // use the updated value of diff here
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Adapter..

```
valueUpdater updater;
  AdapterConstructor(your members .. , valueUpdater updater){

  this.updater = updater;
}

final long countDownInterval = 250;
itemHolder.timer = new CountDownTimer(diff, countDownInterval) {
    public void onTick(long diff) {
        ... 
        updater.onvalueUpdate(diff); // send the updated value to mainactivity
    }

    public void onFinish() {                    
    }
}.start();
```

Details Activity

```
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    joe = intent.getLongExtra("adapterSpanTimeInHours",0);

    weeks = joe / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    days = joe  / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) % 7;
    hours = joe / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
    timeinweeks = String.format(Locale.US, "%2dW %2dD %2dh", weeks, days, hours);

    cb11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cb11);
    cb11.setText(timeinweeks);
}
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Ty, I will give it a try and then circle back.

Comment: No, I tried with no luck.  I ended up giving up on that approach and just loading all of the data from the SQLite database.